# Adding views over a google map in swift?

Tags: ios, google-maps, user-interface, swift

I have used the following code to try and display a label over a google map view but I can simply not see anything apart from a google map with no label...

```
     var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.868,
         longitude:151.2086, zoom:6)

     var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100),     camera:camera)
     mapView.delegate = self

     self.view = mapView

     self.view.addSubview(test)

     self.view.bringSubviewToFront(test)
```

'test' is an outlet to a UILabel add into the xib. Does anyone know how to display this Label over the mapView?

Comment: can you show your implementation for UILabel?

Comment: add the sub views before `self.view = mapView`

Answer (score 3):

```
 self.mapView.bringSubview(toFront: viewName)
```

Answer (score -1):

Same problem that I faced in my project while add an imageview in google map.

try this

```
self.mapView.addSubview(test)
```